# Null pointer exception/Invalid tree for Nested Dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe created from Sparksql like this:

```
val pastAsset = data.filter(data("assetId") === asset.get(0).toString)
```

I know that there are at least 1 rows returned from this query. However when I try to reference the value pastAsset within a foreach statement,

```
pastAsset.filter(data("timestamp") === timeToCompare).
      foreach{ row =>
          println(s"WORKING ON ROW $row ")
        println(s"PAST ASSETS : ${pastAsset}")
    }
```

I get a NPE if I do a count() on the pastAsset value and if I print out the value pastAsset I see:

```
PAST ASSETS : Invalid tree; null:
null
```

I've tried both cacheing the pastAsset value and persisting it, but I still get the same issue. Any ideas why this is happening and how I can get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is pretty complex, so it would be nice if you could make a minimum running example (e.g. with `sc.parallelize(...)`) for us to have a clear picture about what you want to achieve.

Comment: `pastAsset.filter(data("timestamp"))` or `pastAsset.filter(pastAsset("timestamp"))` ? What did you mean to do? If the former one, spark RDDS are immutable and nested operations are not supported. I think that's why you are getting NPE